# Decode base64 mysql

Tags: mysql, base64

Tenho um banco de dados em mysql que algumas colunas dele está codificado em base64. Não tenho familiaridade com programação para desenvolver um script em outra linguagem que faça a decodificação. 
É possível criar um select no sql que decodifique as colunas específicas?

Answer (score 4):

De acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64), existe a função FROM_BASE64()

Exemplo(na documentação):

```
mysql> SELECT TO_BASE64('abc'), FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64('abc'));
        -> 'JWJj', 'abc'
```

Eu não sabia da existência dessa função, mas bastou uma única pesquisa no google para encontrar a resposta. Recomendo que faça isso antes de perguntar, pois poderá lhe poupar tempo.

Comment: Obrigado, mas deu erro: Error Code: 1305. FUNCTION dmail.TO_BASE64 does not exist

Comment: Usei o próprio código do exemplo da documentação: `SELECT TO_BASE64('abc'), FROM_BASE64(TO_BASE64('abc'));`

Comment: Qual é a versão do mysql que você está utilizando?

Comment: Estou usando a versão 5.5.53